# Getting error after implement 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.0.0' and apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

Tags: firebase, react-native, gradle, androidx

I got an error when try to build my apps after adding `implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.0.0'` and `apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'` in my app `build.gradle` file

I have using line `com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.0` and `compileSdkVersion = 28`

I put those lines in my project `build.gradle` file. before I putting those line, I am able to build the project

The error message I got:

> `Manifest merger failed : Attribute application@appComponentFactory value=(android.support.v4.app.CoreComponentFactory) from [com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0] AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-91 is also present at [androidx.core:core:1.0.0] AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-86 value=(androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory). Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory"' to element at AndroidManifest.xml:13:5-354:19 to override.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got this after some research.

I updated my app to use Jetpack (AndroidX), I do this by adding these two lines: `android.useAndroidX=true` and `android.enableJetifier=true` into file `gradle.properties` in the project root directory